How to approach restoring a PSQL DB to a new disk and hosting in a docker container managed by portainer
I've inherited a product that needs to be moved to a new subscription in Azure. The original team that managed it are all gone so trying to reverse engineer how it was set up. I cant snapshot and move the machine due to certain restrictions in the cloud so trying to reconfig on a new server and doing a backup and restore of the DB to new server (which is quite a small DB so easy to copy locally and restore)
They have the application hosted in portainer as a stack. Theres the application container and it connects to a postgres13 docker container where the database resides.
Below is the yaml for the stack
version: '3.2'

services:

  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_DB: database
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/db_password
    secrets:
      - db_password
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U user -d database" ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - public
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints: [ node.role == manager ]

  application:
    image: repo.io/application:latest
    restart: on-failure
    entrypoint: [ "/bin/sh", "-c" , "cp /run/secrets/application_config /app/resources/application-portainer.yml && /entrypoint.sh" ]
    environment:
      SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: prod,swagger,kafka,portainer
    secrets:
      - application_config
    networks:
      - public
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
      labels:
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.http.routers.application.rule=Host(`blabla.com`)"
        - "traefik.http.routers.application.entrypoints=websecure"
        - "traefik.http.services.application.loadbalancer.server.port=8080"
        - "traefik.http.routers.application.service=application"

secrets:
  db_password:
    external: true
  application_config:
    external: true

networks:
  public:
    external: true

volumes:
  data:
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: /application-drive/postgres_data
      o: bind

I'm a bit confused on how to approach the thing. Ive taken a dump of the database to my local machine and I was planning to restore it to my datadisk of my new virtual machine.
Wondering how I then set up the database container on portainer to use this database? Do I just make sure its at the correct path when i create the stack in portainer? (i.e. device: /application-drive/postgres_data)
I didnt try anything yet as I am looking for guidance on the approach

Ive taken a dump of the database, is this a database backup (using pd_dump) or a file copy?

it's a pg_dump taken from pgadmin tool which i was planning to restore to new server with same tool.  wondering should I just take the file system copy to new server and then the psql container would use it at it's dB when I spin it up ? really unsure how it works
